# Why can't I submit an "App Detail Page"?

Tags: web-applications, facebook-apps

I have -- to the best of my knowledge -- entered every required piece of information for my Facebook App Detail page to be submitted (and accepted by FB).  I think I comply with App Center Guidelines and have met all the requirements.

Still I get:

```
Invalid Submission
Before you can submit your app detail page you must first comply with
App Center Guidelines. Please make sure you have specified how your app
integrates with Facebook and have met all the requirements.
Click here to update your integration.
```

**How can I figure out what FB considers missing/errorneous?**

I do would like to submit it! Thanks in advance!

BTW: Where can I officially ask this question?  Is there an "official support" for developers or the community effort is the best effort FB has on this front?

Comment: i share your concerns as well..very poor support to the issues that we come acrooss...

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to go to App Details and turn on some App Center permissions. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/tutorial
Unfortunately FB documentation is not very good and support is still nonexistent.

Comment: Thanks naphier, hope it helps someone else. The project for which the question was posted nearly two years ago has long been dead :(.